# How To Auto Refresh Data on List View Content Page Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I add data on list view but i need to close the program first to show the data. what should i add to auto refresh the content page.

**Class**

```
public class Cart : BindableObject 
{ 
   public string product_id { get; set; } 
   public string name { get; set; } 
   public string price { get; set; } 
   public string image { get; set; } 
   public string quantity { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like : YourListView.Refresh(); ?

Comment: What do you mean by "auto refresh"? The update of the listview when its Itemsource changes or are you looking for a way to update the data for example in polling?

Comment: update the listview if i add a new data @AlessandroAlbi

Comment: no, i dont know what should i do @QuentinCouderc

Comment: can you show your code., the binding of itemsource in code

Comment: public class Cart : BindableObject
    {
        public string product_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string quantity { get; set; }

    }
}
 @ShubhamTyagi

Comment: Use an `ObservableCollection` as item source for your listview, the observable collection notify changes when items are added.

Comment: what is observablecollection? @FabriBertani

Comment: @navyjsuh [ObservableCollection<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Basically when you have static items use `List` as item source and when the items are changing (add new items, delete, update content) use an `ObservableCollection` as source for your `ListView` or `CollectionView`.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to override `OnAppearing()` to refresh the data every time the page loads?  *shrugs*

Answer (score 1):

If the **ViewModel** uses [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding) to create the **Cart** list, then the ListView will update when adding data on runtime.

For example:

```
public ObservableCollection<Cart > CartItems { set; get; }

CartItems.Add(new Cart(){...})
```